# making variables accessable to all classes

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a variable like

```
$shop_id = Configure::read('Settings.SHOP_ID');
```

which I want to make available to all the Controllers, which are extended from AppController.

What will be the best way to do so?

Comment: There is not nearly enough information here to possibly assist you. I assume you are using some sort of framework. Please include that and more details about your application structure.

Comment: He tagged it in [tag:cakephp] @LuckyBurger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define it in the `app/Controller/AppController.php` inside beforFilter callback as follows:

```
function beforeFilter(){
  public var $shop_id = '';
  parent::beforeFilter();
  $this->shop_id = Configure::read('Settings.SHOP_ID');
}
```

So in any of your controller's actions it will be accessible as `$this->shop_id`